# Why doesn't Euler's $e$ in the continuous interest formula show the exponent $n$?

Tags: eulers-number-e

The continuous compounding formula is
$$A = Pe^{rt}$$

However, $e = (1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ provided that $x\rightarrow0$

Then is it correct to rewrite $A = Pe^{rt}$ as $A = P((1+\frac{1}{n})^n)^{rt}$ ?

Comment: the definition of e requires that you take the limit as n goes to infinity

Comment: No, but it is correct to write $Pe^{rt}=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1x\right)^{rt/x}P$.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than directly defining $e$ as
$$
e=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \, ,
$$
it is better to first define the exponential function $\exp$ or $e^x$ as
$$
\exp(x)=e^x=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n \, ,
$$
in which case $e=\exp(1)$. It is not $e$ which is fundamental so much as the exponential function. If we define the exponential function in this way, then we can write $A=Pe^{rt}$ as
$$
P \cdot \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{rt}{n}\right)^n \, .
$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write it showing $n$ in the exponent
$$ Pe^{rt}=P\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{nrt} $$